# Add an html element after 10th character

Tags: jquery, html

How we can add a html element in a sentence after 10th character

Comment: Try to explain your question better, or I think you won't get a useful answer.

Comment: This sort of sounds like you're talking about responding to user input, but I'm sure you're not trying to add an html element to a input or textarea. Please explain the question

Answer (score 6):

```
var $element = $(someselector);
var text = $element.text();
$element.html(text.slice(0, 10) + '<span>new thing</span>' + text.slice(10));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/CjNpD/)

*Note that this works only if $element contains only one object. for a collection, you would use each (I'll detail this code if required).*